# Limpar URL após Insert

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho um insert em php que me redireciona para página mostrando uma mensagem de sucesso/erro através do resultado da url, como posso fazer para atualizar a url após o script do alert ser executado?

Por exemplo a url está: **cadastro.php?msg=error**
Gostaria que ela voltasse para: **cadastro.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 'error') {
    echo '
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <strong>Erro!</strong> Cadastro não efetuado.
        </div> ';
        }elseif (isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 'success'){
            echo '
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Successo!</strong> Cadastro efetuado.
            </div>   
            ';
            }
?>

<script>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
    }, 4000);
</script>
```

Comment: Como assim alterar a URL? Explique melhor editando a pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Pronto, editei.

Comment: Não pode simplesmente mudar a chamada para POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte maneira com JS, eu recentemente elaborei um projeto onde tambem tinha de limpar todos os parâmetros no url, e essa foi a maneira mais facil e funcional que consegui.

```
 var newURL = location.href.split("?")[0];
 window.history.pushState('object', document.title, newURL)
```

Comment: Eu consegui resolver utilizando: window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);

Comment: fico contente por ter conseguido uma solução

Answer (score 0):

Explique melhor.

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }, 4000);
</script>
```

Atualizar a página:

```
window.location.reload()
```

Voltar para a página anterior:

```
javascript:history.back();
```

Redirecionar:

```
window.location.href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/";
```

Trocar o url sem atualizar a página:

```
window.history.pushState('Object', 'new url', 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/');
```